# Time from 100% to online beta

Tags: discussion

I know its not automatic but roughly how long does it take for a site to go from 100% to beta? Days, month or hours?

No sarcasm, or complaint, just genuine curiosity :)

Comment: Do you have a specific complaint (aka example) or are you just curious? If the latter: years!

Comment: Just curious, no complaint at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a manual process and depends on a number of factors, such as whether the Team needs to import data from a SE 1.0 site. The first sites launched fairly quickly, but I think the Team is trying to space out the sites so that they don't have to deal with too many new sites at once. I would estimate that it takes around 2 weeks currently.